# elasticsearch Multisearch request with aggregations

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch

When I perform a single search request with aggregations it works fine. But when I try to perform a multisearch request, aggregations don't seem to work. Isn't it supposed to?

Below is my code, am I doing something wrong (the output is list of hits and no aggregations)? or is msearch not support aggs?

```
var body = {
    "query": {
        "filtered" : {
            "filter" : {
                "and" : filterObj.filters
            }
        }
    }
};

var bodyArray = [];
for (var aggItem in multiaggregations){

    bodyArray.push({ "index" : "myindex", "size" : 0});
    bodyArray.push({ "query": body.query, "aggregations":  aggItem});

}

client.msearch({
        body: bodyArray
});
```

Comment: Can you also show what's in `multiaggregations`? Also, `size:0` doesn't belong to the first line, but to the second. You should not get any hits with `size: 0`. And finally, on the first line `"index"` should be `"_index"` (with underscore).